# What is toString returning for the GsmCellLocation class interface?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out what is being returned when I call this function toString(). In the documentation it says "The {@code toString} method for class {@code Object} returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `{@code @}', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. The returned value looks like this: [22036,36138303,0]

I will include the code used to call the function to.String(). I know that GsmCellLocation is deprecated, I am simply trying to understand what these 3 numbers are. I am looking to update to CellIdentityGsm once I figure this out, thank you for your help.

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation cellLocation) {
        super.onCellLocationChanged(cellLocation);
        if(cellLocation == null) return;
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCellLocationChanged");
        String desc = "\"" + cellLocation.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\" : " + cellLocation.toString();
        textView.setText("Cell Info Logger\nCell Location\n"+desc);
        logger.write(desc);
    } // END onCellLocationChanged
```

This is the documentation for it:

```
    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
     * {@code toString} method returns a string that
     * "textually represents" this object. The result should
     * be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a
     * person to read.
     * It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
     * <p>
     * The {@code toString} method for class {@code Object}
     * returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
     * object is an instance, the at-sign character `{@code @}', and
     * the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
     * object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the
     * value of:
     * <blockquote>
     * <pre>
     * getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
     * </pre></blockquote>
     *
     * @return  a string representation of the object.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

Comment: Because the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.java#128) is: `return "["+ mLac + "," + mCid + "," + mPsc + "]";`

Comment: Thank you! @luk2302

Quick question, do you know how I would transfer from using the CellLocation interface to utilizing the CellIdentityGSM interface for this function?